# Laravel 4: Multi-Page Form on the same route?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hello folks I am stuck.

I want to register a User in Laravel 4. Now the thing is, that I want to first grab the email and password and save them in the database. And in step 2 of the registration process, I want to grab all the other details like first and last name and so on.

The difficulty is, that everything should be under **one route** called signup, for example everything under http://example.org/signup

Another difficulty is, that I have to access the same route with the same methods (GET & POST) twice, because I once get and post the form for Email and Password, and then I get and post the First, Last and Company Name into the Database.

I came up with the following solution, to store everything into the session, because through the session I can access the variables. So whenever I access my UserController I check, if there is data in the session and if yes, redirect to form 2.

Here are all my files:

http://help.laravel.io/d4104cae42f9a2efe1466ce53d086826bc9f6d7f

My Get-Method from the UserController:

```
public function create()
{
    if(Session::has('email')) {
        return View::make('frontend.signup.step2');
    }
    else {
        return View::make('frontend.signup.step1');
    }       
}
```

My Post-Method from the UserController:

```
public function store()
{
    // If User has a email and password in the session from the first create-View
    // his data should be stored and then he gets redirected to a new create-View

    Session::flush();

    Session::put('email', Input::get('email'));
    Session::put('password', Input::get('password'));

    if (Session::has('email')) {

        try
        {
            // Let's register a user.
            $user = Sentry::register(array(
                'email'    => Input::get('email'),
                'password' => Input::get('password'),
            ));

            // Let's get the activation code
            $activationCode = $user->getActivationCode();

            // Send activation code to the user so he can activate the account


            // Save Email in Emaillist
            Email::create(array(
                'email' => Session::get('email')
            ));

            // Redirect 
            return Redirect::action('UserController@create');
        }

        return Redirect::route('signup');   

        }
    else {
        return 'No Session here';
    }
}
```

Here are my routes: 
        Route::get('signup', array('as' => 'signup', 'uses' => 'UserController@create'));
    Route::post('signup', array('as' => 'signup', 'uses' => 'UserController@store'));

For some reason I believe that it gets unneccessary complicated and I believe that there must be another more simple and intuitiv way to solve this, instead with if statements and redirects to the same controller-method.

Nonetheless I came up with some other solutions, for example just using the "signup" as prefix, but I don't like it that way.

```
 Route::group(array('prefix' => 'signup'), function() 
{
    Route::get('/', function(){
        return 'Yeab bababy yea';
    });
    Route::get('step1', array('as' => 'signup.step1', 'uses' => 'UserController@getStep1'));
    Route::post('step1', array('as' => 'signup.step1', 'uses' => 'UserController@postStep1'));
    Route::get('step2', array('as' => 'signup.step2', 'uses' => 'UserController@postStep2'));
    Route::post('step2', array('as' => 'signup.step2', 'uses' => 'UserController@postStep2'));
});
```

Is there any way of accomplishing the task while only using one route and without using clientside Javascript to store the variables in the database? (I am a unexperienced with ajax)

The Goal should be to catch the email and still stay on the same route, like those smart guys here for example:

https://www.crazyegg.com/signup

I hope there is a way. Thank you for your help Internet.

Kind regards,

George

P.S. 
It's 1 am here in Germany, so don't be mad if I don't respond the next couple of hours to comments, because I am going to sleep now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably use the session to store the data temporarily and then retrieve them on the next call and clear them from the session.

Comment: If you are interested in **Step wizard** head to [Bootsnip (search for "Wizard")](http://bootsnipp.com/search?q=wizard).

Comment: Why not make step 1 sign the user up and log them in. Then make step 2 only viewable once logged in?

Comment: I guess I'll take the easy way and use more than one route for it.

The reason I don't want to do it like rybo111 says, is because I am expecting that many people will give an email, but will refuse to give additional data.

So I would like to not sign them up, unless they gave additional data, for example billing information.

Comment: if you dont want people to only give you email you need to use javascript.. when they click the first submit button just hide the fields and show them the second step.. after they complete it submit the form... very simple

Comment: There's a lot to be said for storing step 1's data. For example, you could email them a reminder to complete step 2 after 24 hours. You could analyse the data each month to work out why some users aren't completing step 2.

Comment: This is exactly my intention.